# How to get the top 7 articles shared on the Facebook from my website

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

First of all: my question is not like this question [How to fetch facebook likes, share, comments count from an article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6137414/how-to-fetch-facebook-likes-share-comments-count-from-an-article)
or the unwell answered question [How can I get the list of top 10 artciles shared on Facebook using Graph API or FQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316467/how-can-i-get-the-list-of-top-10-artciles-shared-on-facebook-using-graph-api-or)

For example:

```
mysite.com/viewArticle/1
mysite.com/viewArticle/2
mysite.com/viewArticle/3
...etc
```

Every article page or URL has its own share and like Facebook buttons. I need to know any way using FQL or Graph api that allow me to know the top 7 articles shared or liked from mysite.com/viewArticle/*. Does it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. it's not possible, you'd have to record the `likes` for `each` individual article in a database and work it out on your end.