# How to create a realtime Facebook page fan counter in JS?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, real-time

I created a js script able to get in Json the number of Facebook page fans (fan_count field of Facebook graph api).

The problem is that I can't get it in real-time...

Is it possible with the Facebook graph API? It may be possible with the web hooks but I didn't find fan_count field.

Comment: may be this can help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25034083/is-there-a-way-realtime-store-update-facebook-api-share-like-counts-each-pa

Comment: My guess would be that it is probably not covered by Webhooks, because it would just mean to many requests for pages with a high frequency of likes. I’d say, either use the official Like button and the real-time counter that comes with it – or accept that you can not show this data “real-time,” but have to implement some form of caching on your end. (Because if you don’t, you will run into the API rate limits quickly.)

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. The like button is not very accurate so I am going to create a code refreshing the page every X second.